Login authentication not working properly
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def login():

    if current_user.is_authenticated:

        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))



    form = LoginForm()



    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.form['username']

        password = request.form['password']



        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()



        if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hash, password):

            flash('Login successful!')

            return redirect(url_for('homepage'))

        else:

            flash('Invalid username or password.', 'error')

            return redirect(url_for('login'))



    return render_template('/users/login.html', title='Login', form=form)



# Define is_authenticated outside of the route function

def is_authenticated():

    return current_user.is_authenticated

I've tried adding authentication to login route but still login not registering.

It seems you just queried the user and haven't done anything to make the user log in. For example, to make the user logged in you can login_user method from the flask_login package.
from flask_login import login_user

if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hash, password):
    login_user(user)
    flash('Login successful!')
    return redirect(url_for('homepage'))

After that, to check whether any user logged in, you can use current_user method from the same package.
Eventually, you can use a view like this:
from flask_login import current_user, login_user

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))

    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hash, password):
            login_user(user)
            flash('Login successful!')
            return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
        else:
            flash('Invalid username or password.', 'error')

    return render_template('/users/login.html', title='Login', form=form)

